# Copy indentation from another line in Vim

Tags: vim

I have the following:

```
 line1
   line2
     line3
       line4
         line5
           line6<cursor>
```

What is the best way to get my cursor to the same indentation as line3 so that I can enter line7?

```
 line1
   line2
     line3
       line4
         line5
           line6
     line7
```

Answer (score 3):

Part of this will depend on your mode and settings within Vim. I have `filetype on` and `syntax enable` set in my .vimrc and I find myself, in insert mode, editing a python file, in your exact circumstance all the time. I hit <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> to remove one level of indent and remain in insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

Simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>o</kbd> depending on your mode) and <kbd>TAB</kbd>/<kbd>Backspace</kbd> as necessary, depending on your configuration.

Another approach would be simply create a new line and add `line7` wherever the cursor (indentation) is left at, depending on your configuration, leave insert mode and fix the indentation with <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Well to go in indented mode automatically on a new blank line just press:

**<kbd>S</kbd>**

After that just write your code, go in normal mode and then execute

**<kbd>shift-v</kbd>  <kbd>4<</kbd>**

Here 4 is you indentation level. Just use whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

One can just copy that line with proper indentation level with

```
:-3t.
```

and then edit the copied text or rewrite it completely by typing
the `^C` or `S` Normal-mode commands.

It is also possible to change the indentation level of the current
line in Insert mode without moving the cursor using
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
(See `:help i_^T` and `:help i_^D`.)

Comment: `S` will reindent to the expected indent for that line, at least in my installation. `C` will work, though.

Comment: @Amadan:  Yes, its behavior depends on indentation settings.  `C` does not depend on them.  However, if `startofline` option is disabled, it is necessary to jump to the first non-whitespace character on the line using `^`.